# How to make a Desktop "shortcut" that opens the terminal but under a different directory than the default home?

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, directory, desktop-shortcuts

### Objective

I am looking for an easy way to consistently run a terminal that automatically opens to a specific directory. Is there a way to do that without changing the default directory?

Preferably I just click on a 'shortcut' link and it opens that customized terminal to that directory or maybe runs the CD command for me.

### Full Story

Currently, when I open the terminal (via the Linux Mint GUI menu) it by default 'takes' me to the home directory. This is a fine default choice for the majority of times.

However, there are instances where I wish it would open elsewhere. I don't wish typing the CD command every time, for example:

```
cd Dropbox/GTD
```

Since I go to work on the files located on that specific directory every now and then (enough to be a pain), I am hoping someone can point a way so all I do is ideally

1. Click on a desktop shortcut (script or whatever mechanism)
2. Terminal opens under that specific directory without me typing any commands.
3. I can instantly work on the files located there.
4. If I open another terminal outside that 'shortcut', the terminal opens to the default home directory like usual.

I have a basic understanding working with the command line and Linux in general but am not advanced. Hopefully, you can dumb it down a bit ^_^

Oh and thanks in advance for any tidbits that can help point me in the right direction.

Comment: What's wrong with using the plugin for your file manager that does this?

Comment: Which terminal program are you used to (xterm, urxvt, gnome-terminal, etc)?

Comment: @user1146332 think it's gnome-terminal. The one found on Linux Mint Menu called 'terminal' (similar to the Windows XP start menu)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Not sure what you mean by "plugin for your file manager" but if you mean going to the specifici folder/directory via Thunar (think that's what it's called), right clicking and clicking on "open terminal here", then it requires too many clicks. I would rather just type the CD commands from the terminal. I am just looking for a faster way so I click a button/shortcut from the desktop, it automatically opens a terminal and takes me to a specific directory. Trying to stay in the ternminal environment since I run some commands

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most terminal programs like xterm, urxvt, gnome-terminal have an option to change the starting working directory of the shell.

If you are using gnome-terminal, there is a special command line switch you have to provide to start the shell in a user defined directory. The command line switch I'm talking about is

```
--working-directory=DIRNAME
```

You should take a look at the manual pages of gnome-terminal to verify this.

So, if you want to make a desktop shortcut, the command you have to enter would be:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/you_username/Dropbox/GTD
```

Beforehand feel free to test the command in your current terminal session.

---

**For users on Linux Mint**, follow these instructions

1. Right click on the Desktop
2. Select "Create Launcher"
3. Name this shortcut with whatever name you want
4. In the Command field, enter `gnome-terminal --working-directory=XXX`. Make sure to replace `XXX` with the directory you want it to go to (see the example above)

Comment: Where do I enter that command? Rather, how do I create a desktop shortcut?

Comment: I don't use mint nor i use gnome currently. But i remember that you have to right click on the desktop and create a launcher. A window with several entries pop's up. There must be one entrybox in that window where you have to put the command.

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly! ^^)/ yatta! 

Thanks user1146332. Hope you don't mind me revising your answer a bit and adding the specific steps I took in case others might find useful. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad to see that it's working for you. Feel free to revise my answer (but maybe your reputation count isn't sufficient for this yet)

Answer (score 2):

Create a file named 'something.desktop' and add the following code.
If you are familiar with the commands on launching the 'something.desktop', it will list all the files in the home directory in a terminal.

And, make sure to make 'something.desktop' executable. Fro making any file executable the code is -

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/something.desktop
```

Edit it with your own values

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=IPT
GenericName=IPT
Comment=IPT Desktop icon developed by Mritunjay
Categories=Network;Security;
X-KeepTerminal=true
Icon=/usr/img/ip.png
Exec=gnome-terminal --tab --title="List files" --command="bash -c '/home; ls; $SHELL'"

NoDisplay=true
```

Hope it helps!!